# Asp Sql Data Uniq Id String + Integer +1

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to make an incremental value in my sql table automatically, but I want it to read the previous data and str + int every time.
For example ;
ABC0001
ABC0002
ABC0003
.
.
.
to be continued .

Can you help with this

Comment: Is your `ABC000` always same? What do you mean by `previous data`

Comment: I will register new.
It will check the previous value. Sample ;
In the database, the previous value ABC0001 will automatically check and assign ABC0002 when it makes new records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in many ways. The first way is automate way which is using computed column specification. You can add an auto-increment column and also create another column that will be computed base on the auto-increment column. For example, you can create the USER table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTable](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [UserNo]  AS ('ABC'+ RIGHT('0000' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)) PERSISTED,
  [FirstName] VARCHAR(50),
  [LastName] VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT [PK_UserTable] PRIMARY KEY ([ID] ASC)
)
```

Now you can add data to your table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserTable] ([FirstName],[LastName])
     VALUES ('sample name','sample family name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the Sequence can be made use of
(With your limited data, I assume that you have SQL Server as your DBMS)

```
Create Table T (ColABCIncremtnt varchar(20), Col2 int, Col3 datetime)

CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Id AS INT 
    START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0 NO MAXVALUE

Insert Into T (ColABCIncremtnt,Col2,Col3)
Select 'ABC000' + Convert(varchar(10), next value for dbo.Id), 43,getdate()  

Insert Into T (ColABCIncremtnt,Col2,Col3)
Select 'ABC000' + Convert(varchar(10), next value for dbo.Id), 72,getdate()  

Insert Into T (ColABCIncremtnt,Col2,Col3)
Select 'ABC000' + Convert(varchar(10), next value for dbo.Id), 36,getdate()  

Select * from T
```

if you want to embed the sequence to the table

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T
ADD CONSTRAINT Cnstrnt_Seq
DEFAULT FORMAT((NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.ID),'ABC000#') FOR ColABCIncremtnt;

Insert Into T (Col2,Col3) values
(1,getdate()),  
(2,getdate()),
(3,getdate())

Select * from T
```

Comment: I'm new to Aspnet.
How can I convert these sql commands on asp side. ?

Comment: @melih, if my answer helped you please mark it as answer. And please ask you question as a separate question (with what you tried and what you really need).

Comment: these codes. It does this without checking the "id" in the database.
So when I manually enter "ABC00050", it doesn't do "ABC00051" in the new record

Comment: @melih, your requirements are not clear enough